# Why are HTTP curl/Postman requests to a HTTPS server working? (Node, AWS)

Tags: node.js, http, curl, amazon-ec2, https

I've set up a HTTPS Node server on AWS EC2 which runs on port 4443 and set up Nginx to redirect requests(port 443).

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(4443, function(){
console.log("https server started at port 4443");
});
```

The HTTPS server is working fine, I get a secure connection on browsers and
`curl https://mydomain/apiroute` works

Now, when I do

`curl http://mydomain/apiroute` the requests still work. The same goes for Postman.
I know that I can redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS using something like 301 redirects but my question is, why does the server respond to HTTP API calls inspite of there being no "HTTP" server?

Additionally, I use a letsencrypt generated certificate.

Comment: Could you also post your Nginx config?

Comment: Yes. I'm new to configuring AWS, and followed a tutorial for the same. Here's the config file anyway
https://gist.github.com/avi-jain/a9e9c2477206e7c29e06a88146237700
Thanks